# Does NTPClient updates the ESP32 board date and time?

Tags: esp32

I need to update my current ESP32 date and time in order to correctly report sensor events to server. I need a non blocking implementation....

So far I've used the NTPClient library as follows:

**File Ntp.h**

```
class Ntp
{
private: 
    bool ntpRunning = false;
    
public:
    void setup();
    void loop();
    void print();
    String getDateTime();
};
```

**File Ntp.cpp**

```
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h> // for WiFi shield
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#include <Logger.h>

#include "Ntp.h"

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;

// By default 'pool.ntp.org' is used with 60 seconds update interval and
// no offset
// NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP);

// You can specify the time server pool and the offset, (in seconds)
// additionally you can specify the update interval (in milliseconds).
// NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "europe.pool.ntp.org", 3600, 60000);
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP);


String Ntp::getDateTime()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    time_t nowtime;
    struct tm *nowtm;
    char tmbuf[64];
    char buf[64];

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    nowtime = tv.tv_sec;
    nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);
    strftime(tmbuf, sizeof tmbuf, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", nowtm);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s.%06ld", tmbuf, tv.tv_usec);

    return (String) buf;
}

void Ntp::print()
{
    Serial.print(getDateTime());
    Serial.print(" - ");
    Serial.println(message);
}

void Ntp::setup()
{
    // empty
}

void Ntp::loop()
{
    if (!this->ntpRunning && WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        timeClient.begin();
        this->ntpRunning = true;

        this->print("NTP begin...");
        
    }

    if (timeClient.update())
    {
        this->print("NTP update");
        this->print(timeClient.getFormattedTime());
        this->print("This is the new date and time")
    }
}
```

My output:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:14.857479 - NTP begin
1970-01-01 00:00:15.161455 - NTP update
1970-01-01 00:00:15.168832 - 21:59:29
1970-01-01 00:00:15.169365 - This is the new date and time
```

So, `getFormattedDateTime()` show current date and time, but it's value is not being set on the device - as can be seen in the log date/time trailler.

I can't find on [NtpClient's github page](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/NTPClient) any documentation describing how it works internally, so...

Does `ntpClient.update()` set's the board clock? If yes, what am I missing on my code?

If not, how can I accomplish this - read NTP server and update the device clock?

Comment: The source code is at the link you gave...

Comment: Comment did not help at all... can you please elaborate?

Comment: You complained that the documentation didn't explain how it worked internally. The source code is at the link you gave. It's literally how it works internally.

Comment: OK romkey, got it. I've browsed the source code but could not find out why my code is not working....